# What is the optimal way to transverse a TreeSet from last node to first in java?

Tags: java, performance, treeset

I already have a solution to traverse a TreeSet. My question is related to performance, is the way I implemented the optimal one? See my code example below.

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
  TreeSet ts = new TreeSet();
  ts.add("F");
  ts.add("B");
  ts.add("H");
  ts.add("Z");

  while (!ts.isEmpty())
  {
    String last = (String)ts.last();
    System.out.println(last);
    ts.remove(last);
  }
  // OUTPUT: Z H F B
}
```

Comment: do you really need to delete elements?

Comment: This is tangential to the question, but you should should learn about generics. They add a lot to the type system.

Comment: @OlegMikheev No I dont care to delete the elements, I am removing the element so that the call to .last() will fetch me the new last entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems simple

```
    TreeSet ts = new TreeSet();
    Iterator i = ts.descendingIterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Object next = i.next();
    }
```

or

```
    for(Object e : ts.descendingSet()) {
    }
```

for Java below 1.6 you can try

```
    TreeSet tmp = new TreeSet(Collections.reverseOrder());
    tmp.addAll(ts);
    for(Object e : tmp) {
    }
```

Comment: Yes this seems simple way to do it but it works only on jdk 6 and won't work on jdk 5, I prefer a solution which works with jdk 5 although I am using jdk 6

Comment: @Wael This is the solution unless you have a requirement to support versions earlier than 6. There are several enhancements to java.util in 6 that make code simpler and cleaner.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan ok thank you all. I will go with this change. It is acceptable since we recently migrated to JDK 6, its my mistake that in eclipse I was still using jdk 5 which didn't show me the ts.descendingIterator() call.

Comment: @Evgeniy we had the same idea at the same time. But I think 1.5 version work only if you explicitly specify the parameter type of the elements (Object doesnt implements comparable).

Answer (score 0):

A JDK 5 compatible way: create a new new collection with the comparator reversed.

```
TreeSet<String> trev = new TreeSet<String>(Collections.reverseOrder());
trev.addAll(ts);
//now you can just iterate which the usual forward iterator.
Iterator i = trev.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    String next = i.next();
}
```